# JasperReports: How to display multi language on one page and same as label

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to display 2 or more language on one page and same as label or text field. Please help me for provide solutions for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a resource bundle (.properties) file for your report.  Have entries in the bundle for each language you want to display, then pass them to the text fields as $R{key}. In iReport, select File/New then from the list of options select Resource Bundle. Entries are key:value pairs.  The key is what goes in the text field as $R{key} and the value is displayed.